# How to view folder from Google drive using Service account API without sharing to service account email

Tags: google-drive-api, streamlit, service-accounts

Description:
[Workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hc85q.png)

- I have a client who has a folder containing text files that I need for processing and result display
- The client will share the folder with me using share folder in which he will specify my test email address.
- This folder will be displayed in the drive of my test email address
- I have already created a service account to process the data.
- I also need to be able to view the folders in the test email drive
- I will be displaying the folders and files using Streamlit

Problem:

- Currently I go to my test drive and in the "Shared with me " Tab, I can see the folder that has been shared with me by the client.
  Step 1: * I share this folder with my service account email and only then can I see the folder using my program.
- If i do not share with service account email, I will not be able to see the folder in my program

Program:

```
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY_PATH, scopes=SCOPES)

service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

results = service.files().list(
    pageSize=1000, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name, mimeType, parents)").execute()

items = results.get('files', [])

for item in items:
     print(f'{item["name"]} ({item["id"]}), Mime Type: {item["mimeType"]}, Parents: {item.get("parents", [])}')
```

Requirements:

- Is it possible for me to skip Step 1 in the Problems section and configure my service account to directly take files without having to share the folder with my service account email.

Currently a workaround that I have found is to share the Client folder with the service account email and the test account email. So I can view the folder in both the program and the google drive of the test account.
But my question is if there is a better method to achieve the same result?